# Как очистить input по нажатию на checkbox

Tags: jquery

Написал скрипт, который, по идее, должен очищать инпут, когда `checkbox:checked`. А когда `checkbox:not(:checked)`, то в инпуте должно отображаться значение, которое было до того, как инпут очистили. Но мой код не работает.

```
$(function() {
    var input = $('#back_date');
    var value = input.val();
    $('#way-indent').change(function() {
        var clearence = this.checked ? '' : value;
        $(input).val(clearence);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно, но у меня работает. Продлагаю записывать предыдущее значение в data-аттрибут.

```js
$(function() {
    var input = $('#back_date');
    var value = input.val();
    $('#way-indent').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            input.data('value', input.val());
            input.val('');
        } else {
            input.val(input.data('value'));
        }
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="back_date" type="text" value="Test value" /><br />
<label><input id="way-indent" type="checkbox" />Очистить</label>
```